# Not redirecting to desired page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I get the `loginState` in Navigation, so after successful login system should redirect to `Profile` screen. Now after successful login, it is not Redirecting to profile screen.
I have read few tutorials but all with complex details, I would like to have some simple way of implementing this, as I have only 4 screens.

I have added a demo below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-ellis-2h3pd?file=/src/components/Home.js

Comment: are you storing user is logged in or not details, at global level?

Comment: @tejal, I am not storing that, not sure how to achieve that mate.

Answer (score 2):

To use `props.history` in a component, you should wrap your component with `withRouter`

---

```
 import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

 ....rest code...

 export default withRouter(Login)
```

---

Another way to achieve your desired behavior is at route declaration itself do

---

```
  <Route path="/login" render={()=> loginstate ? < Redirect to= 'profile' /> : <Login/>} />
```

---

What more adapt to a real scenario usage, while `loginstate` isn't live just a `Login` component but at some root place at your project

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a funcional component it won't re-render and therefore calling the ternary in the return statement again. What I recomment you to do is, in the `handleSubmit`:

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const userEmail = "sample@test.com";
  const userPassword = "1234";

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (email === userEmail && password === userPassword) {
      alert("Success");
      setLoginState(true);
      props.history.replace('/');
    } else {
      alert("Login details not correct !");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login_wrapper">
      <div className="login_player_column_layout_one">
        <div className="login_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="myForm">
            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
              <h2 className="formTitle">Login</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="loginfillContentDiv formElement">
              <label>
                <input
                  className="inputRequest formContentElement"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  className="inputRequest formContentElement"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                <span className="loginValidationText" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="loginsubmitButtonDiv formElement">
              <button type="submit" className="submitButton">
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then you can avoid using the `<Redirect />` component. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: It says `props` not defined

Comment: should work now, you need to add props to the params of your functional component.
`const Login = (props) => ...`

Comment: That error got resolved now. But as I need to navigate to `Profile` screen after login, not Home. I have tried `props.history.replace('/profile');` and not working

Comment: do `props.history.push('/profile')` instead. Should fix it. Also make sure you have the route properly registered.

Answer (score 0):

1. On successful sign in, store flag in local storage

   localStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn', true);
2. App.js : Allow user to access signing in related pages without restriction

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/signIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/signUp" component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

3. PrivateRoute.js : if user is not logged in always get redirected to sign in

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('userLoggedIn')
            ? <Component {...props}></Component>
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signIn', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
);
```

5. Dashboard.js : After sign in user can access Dashboard

```js
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <div>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={MY_PROFILE} />
                  <Route exact path="/myProfile" component={MyProfile} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written all my components in using React Hooks though...

Comment: `Home, Login` nav links are available for all users. `Profile` will be displaying once the user login is successfull.

Comment: Using react hooks in all component will not be a problem. Keep your routing file privateRoute and DashboardRoute separate to make it easy.

You have to add new Routes like Home etc in Dashboard switch, so it will be accessible only after login